# PowerShell and MS Word 2013 Charting, ForEach

Tags: powershell, foreach, ms-word

I have been working on an automated word document and have hit a problem with a foreach query that I cant get to output correctly. I have the below data:

```
Date,       server 1, server 2, server 8, server 12
19/08/2014, 4.24,     5.8,      2.05,     1.0
20/08/2014, 6.4,      3.8,      5.05,     2.1
```

however my script keeps outputting it as:

```
Date,       server 1, server 2, server 8, server 12
20/08/2014, 6.4,      3.8,      5.05,     2.1
```

Basically the first line gets overwritten by subsequent lines and then only the final line is present.

Please see my code below:

```
#### Create Word Document ####

$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $true
$doc = $word.documents.add()
$selection = $word.selection
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

# Create a new chart
$docChart = $Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart()
$docChart.Chart.Type = "1"
$docChart.chart.SubType = "2"
$docChart.Chart.ChartStyle = "2"
$docChart.Chart.Legend.AutoScaleFont = "true"
$docChart.Chart.HasTitle = "True"
$docChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Formula = "VM Memory Consumption"

$cells = $docChart.chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet.cells

$columns = $MyData | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select Name

foreach($column in $columns){
    $row=1
    $col++

    $column2 = $column.Name
    $cells.Item($Row,$col) = "$column2"

    $MyData | ForEach-Object{
        $Row1=2
        $col
        $date = $_.c3
        $array = ($_ | Select-Object $Column2)."$Column2"

        $Array | ForEach-Object{

            $cells.Item($row1,$col) = "$array"
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help resolving this.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: $Row1 = 2 in your loop? Shouldn't you increment that value?

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me resolve the issue answer is below

Answer (score 1):

The following code has resolved my issue, basically I create the $row1 variable in the first foreach loop and then $row1++ on the 2nd foreach loop, this then puts the data in as expected.

```
#### Create Word Document ####

$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $true
$doc = $word.documents.add()
$selection = $word.selection
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

 # Create a new chart
 $docChart = $Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart()
 $docChart.Chart.Type = "1"
 $docChart.chart.SubType = "2"
 $docChart.Chart.ChartStyle = "276"
 $docChart.Chart.Legend.AutoScaleFont = "true"
 $docChart.Chart.HasTitle = "True"
 $docChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Formula = "VM Memory Consumption"
 $docChart.chart.Legend.Position = "-4107"

$cells = $docChart.chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet.cells

$columns = $MyData | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select Name

foreach($column in $columns){
    $row=1
    $col++
    $row1=1
    $column2 = $column.Name
    $cells.Item($Row,$col) = "$column2"

    $MyData | ForEach-Object{
        $row1++
        $date = $_.c3
        $array = ($_ | Select-Object $Column2)."$Column2"

        $Array | ForEach-Object{
            $cells.Item($row1,$col) = "$array"
        }
    }
}
```